# How do I modify the _trackPageview output of the Google Analytics Drupal 7 module?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am working with the Google Analytics (googleanalytics) module in Drupal 7 and I need to get search categories added to the code. The module itself doesn't seem to offer any hooks in for an operation like this. I am considering trying to go into the storage of drupal_add_js to modify it. But I don't like how hacky that is.

So my next thought is to modify the module. But I would rather not do this to a contrib module. So any thoughts? I have been also wondering if I can push _trackPageview twice to Google on the same page, with the second time being with the search query and category. But I don't know how Google Analytics will work with that option.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how to pass custom values to Google Analytics ?", then why wouldn't you use the [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) feature of Google Analytics, populated by custom tokens ?

1. Create custom token containing search categories (via [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7) and [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7))
2. In Google Analytics Module interface, in the "Custom Variables" fieldset, add your custom token

Comment: No, Google Analytics has a fairly new feature that goes along with their search settings. Now instead of just passing a search term to GA you can also pass a search category. This is completely separate from custom variables.